# solc.exe - Application Error The application was unable to start correctly

Tags: solidity

Solidity compiler is not working on Win 7 Enterprise (64-bit) SP1.

It was downloaded from https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases
Version 0.4.19 (solidity-windows.zip)

solc --version

Error : solc.exe - Application Error
The application was unable to start correctly (0x...). Click OK to close the application.

Content of solidity-windows folder :

```
<DIR>          .
<DIR>          ..
       440,120 msvcp140.dll
     6,201,344 solc.exe
    16,123,392 soltest.exe
```

Comment: Probably more useful to have this post on: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Seems answer is located here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11081/install-solc-compiler-on-windows-8

So either MS Visual Studio needs to be installed (suggested 2015) or JS script needs to be written (using Node.js solc module)

The remaining concern is that MS Visual Studio is too huge for installation for resolving mentioned issue. **Is anyone aware what exact software component(s) from MS Visual Studio are needed?** And described solution with JS script returns errors for the contracts which have import statements.

```
>node compileWithoutInstalledMSStudio -f file1.sol
Solc version : 0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.Emscripten.clang
Read file : ../solidity/file1.sol
COMPILATION ERROR :
:4:1: ParserError: Source "file2.sol" not found: File not supplied initially.
import "./file2.sol";
```

^----------------------------^